# XMLsimple get value of next element

Tags: php, xml, xml-simple

This is a small part of the XML file I am reading:

```
<hotel>    
<Location>
    <Identifier>D5023</Identifier>
    <IsAvailable>true</IsAvailable>
    <Availability>
        <TimeStamp>2015-06-11T16:04:23.887</TimeStamp>
        <Rooms>525</Rooms>
        <Beds>845</Beds>
    </Availability>
</Location>
<Location>
    ect.
</Location>
</hotel>
```

Using XMLsimple I want to get the number of available rooms for location D5023 (and other locations). But because the Identifier is a child from the Location attribute I am struggling to get the right data.

This is what I came up with, but obviously this doesnt work

```
$hotel->Location->Identifier['D5023']->Availability->Rooms;
```

How can I get this right?

Comment: not sure, do you mean PHP's simpleXML? Or is there XMLsimple for PHP as well? please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) to get specific part of XML by complex criteria, for example :

```
$xml = <<<XML
<hotel>    
<Location>
    <Identifier>D5023</Identifier>
    <IsAvailable>true</IsAvailable>
    <Availability>
        <TimeStamp>2015-06-11T16:04:23.887</TimeStamp>
        <Rooms>525</Rooms>
        <Beds>845</Beds>
    </Availability>
</Location>
<Location>
    ect.
</Location>
</hotel>
XML;
$hotel = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$result = $hotel->xpath("/hotel/Location[Identifier='D5023']/Availability/Rooms")[0];
echo $result;
```

**output :**

```
525
```

**<kbd>[Demo](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/HAzBz3)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

there are more Location so you have too loop on :

```
foreach ($hotel->Location as $l) {
    if ("D5023" === $l->Identifier) {
        var_dump($l->Availability->Rooms);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you load your file and loop through the XML file and check the ID , don't forget to cast the xml from object to string so you can compare 2 strings to each other and not an object to a string.

```
if( $xml = simplexml_load_file("path_to_xml.xml",'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING) ) 
        {
            echo("File loaded ...");

            // loop through XML 
            foreach ($xml->hotel as $hotel)
            { 
                // convert the xml object to a string and compare it with the room ID
                if((string)$hotel->Location->Identifier == "D5023")
                {
                    echo("there are ".$hotel->Location->Availability->Rooms."Available room in this hotel");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        echo("error loading file!");
```

hope that helps !